# is it possible to track input device when request is redirected

Tags: java, apache, httpwebrequest, request, httprequest

I am rewriting an URL in Apache and forwarding the request to another server.

Now my question is can I able to get the details of device from which the request has been made originally.

Say for example If I am making the request from iPhone, can I be able to get the model of this phone.

Comment: no this is not possible. why don't you pass it via a parameter?

Comment: are you using mod_proxy or mod_proxy_ajp to forward the request?

Comment: @brettw. I am using mod_rewrite

Comment: ok, so you are using mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL. what is forwarding the request to another server?  it is my understanding of mod_rewrite that it cannot itself forward any request out of Apache.  So either it is sending a redirect to the client, or you are using another module to handling forwarding the rewritten URL. If it a redirect, the client will simply access the new URL directly and you will receive all of the request headers.  If it some other mod_ there are various options for forwarding headers depending on the module.

Comment: @brettw Thank you for the response. I just using mod_rewrite to modify the URL. I am not making any changes other than that. So in this case as you mentioned the request again comes to client and access the redirected URL. Can I then access client details then.

Comment: You must use the User-Agent header to determine the origin of the request.  The User-Agent for iPhone will look something like this: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the User-Agent header to determine the origin of the request. The User-Agent for iPhone will look something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16
```